# jQuery function to get objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object

I want to change this old JavaScript function

```
function getObj(x) {
    this.obj = document.getElementById(x);
    this.style = document.getElementById(x).style;
}
```

by another function using jQuery. Something like this:

```
function getObj(x) {
    this.obj = $(x.obj);
    this.style = $(x.obj).style;
}
```

Of course, this one is not working.

Comment: If x only contains obj then why do you want to pass an object with one property?

Comment: from your original, the equivalent would be $(x) and not $(x.obj)

Comment: You will never (!) need a function like this when you use jQuery. There is no point in trying to re-create it.

Comment: Thank you pimvdb for your response. 'x' is the name of the object.

Comment: Thank you Matt. The problem is the missing '#'.

Comment: Tomalak, I tried to recreate the function because I want not to change the getObj function in several pages.

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
function get(x){
    var x = $('#'+x);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eCZZn/

Comment: Thank you SAnandnarayan. This is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3):

```
function getObj(x) {
this.obj = $("#" + x);
this.style = $("#" + x).style;
}
```

Comment: Thank you MCSI. With this function I can continue using the old function.

Answer (score 1):

To get object from jQuery collection use `get()` method:

`this.obj = $('#some_id').get(0);`

JQuery documentation for get(): http://api.jquery.com/get/

Comment: Thank you rogal11. I didn't know about get(0).